# Decrease topic replication factor after Kafka brokers removed from cluster and failed reassignments

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, cloudera, kafka-topic, kafka-partition

The topic replication factor has increased to 45 while the number of available Kafka brokers in the cluster is 40.

This happened due to repeated stuck partition reassignments which were stopped.

`kafka-topics --topic top --zookeeper zoo_url --describe`

shows

`Partition: 0   Leader: 20464   Replicas: 20464,20765,1882,20870,873,898,20752,16789,17181,20743,20854,20762,894,20459,20851,21070,20757,20766,20763,890,21173,20852,895,21314,20767,883,20467,16787,21071,20750,887,20760,7067,876,20764,891,20768,4880,20769,16788,20756,886,21172,1582,871,16827 Isr: 20464,20765,1882,20870,873,898,20752,16789,17181,20743,20762,894,20459,21070,20757,20766,20763,890,21173,895,21314,20767,883,20467,16787,20750,887,20760,7067,876,20764,891,20768,4880,20769,16788,20756,886,21172,871,16827 ...`

Some of the replicas are not part of the cluster.

Running:

`kafka-reassign-partitions --zookeeper zoo_url --topics-to-move-json-file assign.json --generate --broker-list ...`

fails with below error

```
Partitions reassignment failed due to replication factor: 45 larger than available brokers: 21
kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: replication factor: 45 larger than available brokers: 21
    at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.assignReplicasToBrokers(AdminUtils.scala:117)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$$anonfun$generateAssignment$1.apply(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:110)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$$anonfun$generateAssignment$1.apply(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:108)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:116)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$.generateAssignment(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:108)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$.generateAssignment(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:91)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$.main(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:50)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand.main(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala)
```

`--broker-list` argument input are ids of online brokers.

How to force decreasing of topic replication factor?

The only solution that worked is decreasing replication factor of one partition  by running

`kafka-reassign-partitions --zookeeper zoo_url --reassignment-json-file /tmp/assign.json  --execute`

when `/tmp/assign.json` is like below

`{ "partitions": [ { "partition": 0, "replicas": [20743,20762,894,20459,20757,895,20467,20760], "topic": "topic" } ], "version": 1 }`

And then rerunning partition assignment (generation of assignment and executing it)

Kafka `0.9.0.1` is deployed as part of Cloudera.

Comment: So, I'm going to ask... Why do you need more than 3-5 replicas?

Answer (score 0):

You can add more than one partition in the `{ "partitions": [` list, but using `kafka-reassign-partitions` is the only built-in way to handle this. There may be external tools that can manage to programmatically generate that JSON, but they may also error when trying to lookup unknown broker ids that are currently in the assignment